# Migrating Moodle site from Ubuntu to REHL 7

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, redhat, moodle

We are trying to migrate our current `Moodle 2.9.1` installation from our `Ubuntu` server to the new `REHL 7`.

We took the following steps:

1. Copied the directories

> old-/var/www/moodledata 
>                    new-/data/www/moodledata
>
> old-/var/www/html/moodle
>
> new-/data/www/html/moodle

2. Made `MySQL-Dump` of the database.
3. Made the same `Apache` configuration as on the Ubuntu

We made an `redirect` from the old `http://moodlesite.com` to `https://moodlesite.com` and got:

> Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through
>   `http://moodlesite.com` address, sorry. Please notify
>   server administrator.

Then followed these steps:

```
Change the following file: /home/xxxxxx/public_html/moodle/lib/setuplib.php
Change -  setuplib.php
Redirect ($CFG->wwwroot, get_string('wwwrootmismatch', 'error', $CFG->wwwroot), 3);
for
Redirect ($CFG->wwwroot, get_string('wwwrootmismatch', 'error', $CFG->wwwroot), 0);

Now when you access the link, Moodle redirects immediately to the www.<your registered domain> without the warning message.

Another solution is to make changes in .htaccess file

***************************************************************
suphp_configpath /home/myroot/public_html/php.ini
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.domainname.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
 i.e. replace the myhost.com  with your domain name
***************************************************************
```

And got `HTTP Error 500`, checked the Apache permissions:

```
[root@srv24 html]# pwd
/data/www/html
[root@srv24 html]# chown -R apache:apache moodle/
[root@srv24 html]# chown -R apache:apache ../moodledata/
[root@srv24 html]# chmod -R 755 moodle/
[root@srv24 html]# chmod -R 755 ../moodledata/
[root@srv24 html]# systemctl restart httpd.service
[root@srv24 html]# apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

But the error still remains.

What have we missed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `wwwroot` value in `config.php`?

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://moodlesite.com';
```

Also did you copy the data folder from the old server to the new server?

```
$CFG->dataroot  = '/moodle/data/folder';
```

Migration instructions - https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Moodle_migration

Comment: Hi Russel, yes we had everything in `config.php` up to date. `wwwroot` is with the new address and dataroot is with the new `/data/www/html/moodle`. Still getting http 500 error...